# Como edito o email no git?

Tags: git, github

Havia colocado um email como padrão na conta do github, e consequentemente na config global do git mas o problema que eu encerrei a conta do yahoo e incluí o hotmail como principal  nas configurações do github, só que, está dando esse problema.
Pesquisei mas não achei nenhum comando para fazer a edição do email.
Enfim, como edito no terminal o email novo no git?

[image: como editar o email no git?]

Answer (score 3):

Um jeito simples é editar o arquivo CONFIG que fica dentro da pasta .git

lá você edita o seguinte:

```
[user]
  name = seu nome vem aqui
  email = aqui vai seu email
```

Há comandos via linha de comando, mas isso deve resolver o seu problema.

**Atualização**

Essa mudança vale para um repositório específico. Para uma configuração global você pode fazer a mesma alteração no arquivo .gitconfig que fica dentro do seu home.

Se windows deve ser `c:\User\seu usuário`.

Se linux deve ser `/home/seu_usuario`.

Você pode ainda fazer isso via linha de comando:

```
git config --global user.name "SEU NOME"
git config --global user.email "SEU EMAIL"
```

Mas como citei, o resultado final será o mesmo.

Comment: mas eu baixei o sourcetree...

Comment: Não tem problema, vai ter o arquivo de qualquer maneira dentro da pasta .git. Note que essa pasta é oculta por omissão. Habilite a exibição de arquivos ocultos.

Comment: Eu o vi aqui. Mas achei estranho porque tinha o email recente lá. Mas quando commito e faço push dá o mesmo problema...não tem um comando de email e senha para alterar?

Comment: A senha você deve mudar no seu repositório remoto. No local não tem senha.

Comment: Não sei o que faço...Está com erros ainda...

Comment: Via web você consegue se autenticar no github? Note que você deve usar o usuário e senha do github, não interessa o email nesse caso

Comment: Consigo logar no github. normal.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36390/discussion-between-josivan-and-aline-gonzaga).